# C# Why Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.UpsertResponse could not be set by Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, sdk, dynamics-crm

I use reflection to set the property `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages.UpsertResponse.Target`, but I failed. The code is as follows:

```cs
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*DemoClass instance = new DemoClass();*/
            UpsertResponse instance = new UpsertResponse();
            Console.WriteLine("readonly value : {0}", instance.Target);
            string propName = "Target";
            EntityReference propValue = new EntityReference();
            propValue.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            changeProperty(instance, propName, propValue);

            Console.WriteLine("new value : {0}", instance.Target.Id);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void changeProperty(Object instance, string propName, Object propValue)
        {
            var field = instance.GetType().GetField("<" + propName + ">k__BackingField", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            field.SetValue(instance, propValue);
        }
    }
    public class DemoClass
    {
        public EntityReference Target { get; }
    }
}
```

`DemoClass` is similar to `UpsertResponse` with a `Target` property. `changeProperty` works for change instance's property using reflection. A NullPointerException is throwed in function `changeProperty` because `fieldInfo` is `null`. But when I use the commented `DemoClass instance = new DemoClass();`, this works just fine. How could I solve this problem? Is there a way to set `UpsertResponse`?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that `UpsertResponse.Target` returns a value from a backing field `<Target>k__BackingField` is wrong.

If you decompile Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll, you will see something like

```
public EntityReference Target
{
    get
    {
        if (base.Results.Contains("Target"))
        {
            return (EntityReference)base.Results["Target"];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

So to manipulate the value of `Target` you will have to modify the `Results` collection. As written in the comments, this can be done by

```
response.Results.AddOrUpdateIfNotNull("Target", entityReference);
```

Comment: I use `response.Results.AddOrUpdateIfNotNull("Target", entityReference);` to solve it, thank you!